# Flutter Issue - Keystore file not set for signing config release

Tags: android, flutter

Im Running the command  `flutter build appbundle --release`  or  `flutter build apk --release` through the terminal and I keep getting these errors:

```
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-3.0.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\auth\FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugi
n.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file not set for signing config release
```

I've tried everything, I went through the [build and release guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#configure-signing-in-gradle) , I checked for more than 5 hours as of right now similar problems here and in other forums, and really I'm quite clueless

Any Help Would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

These two first notes are not errors. It is a known warning related to Firestore. Dont worry about that:

```
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
```

Your problem is about the Keystore file:

```
 Keystore file not set for signing config release
```

**Solution**:
Run these 2 commands and adjust according to your own path:

```
    cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin


    keytool -genkey -v -keystore C:\Users\yourNAme\key.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

More details in this link:

https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#signing-the-app

Comment: I've already signed the app, I've the correct path for the storeFile, and I put the key.properties and upload-keystore at the same folder, android/app. it doesn't let me run cd commands at all for some reason though and keytool command I had to use the path of java binary